# Meaning of message in access log file

Tags: web-server, http, weblogic, sun-one

I am seeing the issue in one of my web server access logs which is proxying to weblogic

```
...-0400] "GET /" 500 32
```

Can you suggest what this might mean. It is a sunone web server

Comment: Someone tried to access the root page for a domain, and got a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @ceejayoz said `500` indicates the [error response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html). `32` is the size of the [response in bytes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).

I generated an example log for the "common" format log entry that sunone uses by default;

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Ma...100] "GET /Bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2445 <--- correct formatted HTTP request
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Ma...100] "GET /" 200 11172   <--- HTTP/1.0 request
```

The example request is missing a `HTTP/1.1` from the request line, so its an old style (HTTP/0.9 compatible) HTTP/1.0 request. So it unlikely to be a request from a browser. 
It could be a manual telnet request e.g. `telnet localhost 80`, or someone using wget/curl in HTTP/1.0 mode, or a http client library.

As @mgorven mentioned, its a server error, hence it is either being returned locally from the default virtual server (because thats where the HTTP/1.0 requests end up) or from the remote proxied server.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but would this be a 500 response from the web server to the source which was hitting, or a response that it got back from the server to which it was proxying to.

Comment: the docs for sunone are not that [revealing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/817-1831-10/agaphttp.html#wp13183), indicating just a `Server error`. You can still match up the time of the log entry to the log files on the proxy-target instance, or if this is happening frequently from some host XXX then you could use `tcpdump -s0 -w /tmp/hostXXX host XXX` to capture the requests and inspect them fully.

Comment: also, just try it and see. do `telnet localhost 80` on the sunone server, and at the prompt type `GET /` and see what it puts in the logs

Comment: An badly formatted request should return status code [400](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1), so unless SunOne has a bug in this regard this doesn't explain what is happening.

Comment: @mgorven hmm. i just checked the [rfc](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-5) and it seems that a `GET /` request is a valid HTTP/1.0 request. So point taken about "badly formatted requests" .

Answer (score 0):

This means that the request failed with status code [500](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1), which indicates that an error occurred in the server. It could have occurred in either SunOne or WebLogic, so you need to check the error logs of both to determine why it happened. (If SunOne encountered a network problem when communicating with WebLogic it should return a [502](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.3) or [504](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.5) status code, so this is an actual application error.)